# How do I specify a path in CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, fastapi

I am trying to deploy an app in AWS Lambda. I am having issue accessing the `handler` that is deep inside the directory structure. Here is a simplified version of the issue.

My dir structure looks something like:

```
.
├── app.py
├── Dockerfile
├── events
│   ├── event.json
├── requirements.txt
├── template.yaml
```

And, here the contents of the files:

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI(title='Serverless Lambda FastAPI', root_path="/Prod/")

class BodyModelAdd(BaseModel):
    num1: int
    num2: int

@app.post("/add", tags=["Add Two Numbers"])
def add(item: BodyModelAdd):
    return {'result': {'num1': item.num1, 'num2': item.num2, 'sum': item.num1 + item.num2}}

handler = Mangum(app=app)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

**event.json**

```
{
    "body": "{\"num1\": 1, \"num2\": 2}",
    "resource": "/add",
    "path": "/add",
    "httpMethod": "POST",

    "requestContext": {
        "path": "/add",
        "resourcePath": "add",
        "httpMethod": "POST"
    }
}
```

**requirements.txt**

```
fastapi==0.85.1
uvicorn==0.19.0
mangum==0.16.0
pydantic==1.10.2
```

**template.yaml**

Note: I am very very new to Docker and AWS Lambda, and do not really have a good grasp of the contents of the yaml, but I grabbed this from a tutorial and it seems to work.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.9
  Sample SAM Template for api_qna

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 600
    MemorySize: 1024

Resources:
  PracticeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
        NonRoot:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1

Outputs:
  PracticeApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod"
  PracticeFunction:
    Description: "Practice Tab Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt PracticeFunction.Arn
  PracticeFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created"
    Value: !GetAtt PracticeFunctionRole.Arn
```

To test it locally:

Once I have all these files, I first run `sam build` and then `sam local invoke PracticeFunction --event events/event.json`, and it gives the expected result as follows:

```
<some details deleted>

... 

{"statusCode": 200, ..., "body": "{\"result\":{\"num1\":1,\"num2\":2,\"sum\":3}}", ...}%
```

So far so good. However, let me move the *app.py* to inside a dir as given below:

```
.
├── ...                   <-- app.py was here earlier
├── Dockerfile
├── events
│   ├── event.json
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── dir1
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── app.py        <-- app.py moved here inside src/dir1/
├── template.yaml
```

The content of all the files are still the same (as given above). Now if I run `sam build` and then `sam local invoke PracticeFunction --event events/event.json`, it gives me an error as follows:

```
<some details deleted>
...
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "6cad0c02-73f4-4484-98fd-86c851d13548", "stackTrace": []}%
```

So it was expecting the *app.py* in the root dir and it could not find. Now my question is **how do I handle this case when my *app.py* is not in the root project directory?** Where do I specify the path to the *app.py*?

If I simply replace `CMD ["app.handler"]` with `CMD ["./src/dir1/app.handler"]` in the *Dockerfile* it gives an error saying `{"errorMessage": "the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '..src.dir1.app'", "errorType": "TypeError", ...`. I have also done some search but no luck yet (I must be missing something very trivial).

Sorry about the rather long post, but wanted to include all the details. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: in `Dockerfile` add  WORKDIR

Comment: @Para I tried to include `WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src/dir1` just before the `CMD ["app.handler"]`, but it still gives me the error `{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError" ...`. Wondering if I am including the `WORKDIR` correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69527975/aws-lambda-in-python-handler-from-parent-directory) + what @Para had suggested above, I added `ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"` followed by `WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src/dir1` just before the `CMD ["app.handler"]`, and now it works! However, in a non AWS Lambda related Dockerfile, just setting the `WORKDIR ...` had worked without setting the `ENV ...`. So, is setting the `ENV ...` specific to Dockerfile related to AWS Lambda? Really a newbie to this, can anyone can shed some light please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following example works for FastAPI app.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
```

**main.py**

```python
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    """Initialize application services"""
    # await db.init()
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
handler = Mangum(app)
```

**Dockerfile**

```docker
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/requirements.txt 

# Copy source code
COPY ./app/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/app/

# !!! Adding code to python path
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Set woring directory
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/app

# Run the app
CMD ["main.handler"]
```

Without adding `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` to `PYTHONPATH` lambda can't find module `main` and handler in it.